# Broken img tag in ngFor [Angular] [Ionic] [Android]

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a modal with ngFor and img tags in it.
After a few cycles, img tags shows broken images. The problem is not the url, because if i invert the array of urls, the problem is always with the latest emojis.

[image: Modal]

This is my code:

```
<div class="emoji" *ngFor="let emoji of emojis; trackBy: index;" (click)="add_msg(emoji)">
    <img src="{{ emoji }}">
</div>
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Can you post the content of emojis ?

Comment: The content of emojis are all the pngs of Twemoji. If i invert the array of all emojis, the problem is always with the latest emojis.

Comment: When you serve your ionic project in browser, do you get any errors ? What src do you get if you inspect the last emojis src ?

Comment: When i serve my ionic project in browser i get no errors. Src of the last emoji is: http://localhost:8100/assets/imgs/emoji/1f1ff-1f1fc.png and it's correct.

Comment: (Broken images are only on Android. iOS works as expected)

Comment: Do you get errors on your console on Android ? (You can use the chrome inspector - check the console and inspect the page to see if the URL are present)

Comment: Yes, urls are there @saperlipopette

Comment: Like i said, the problem is no the url, because if i invert the array of urls, the problem is always with the latest emojis. @saperlipopette

Comment: Okay and no error on your JS console ? Could you share the debug apk ?

Comment: For now i temporary resolve with infinite scroll

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting trackBy: index. Can you remove it and see the result?

Answer (score 0):

I think CSS may cause an issue.

Try modifying the class used in the div tag i.e. `emoji` by altering/providing the dimensions for the image like height, width and padding.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the images do not exist?

You can try this?

```
<div class="emoji" *ngFor="let emoji of emojis; trackBy: index;" (click)="add_msg(emoji)">
    <img [src]="emoji">
</div>
```

Comment: Nothing’s change

Comment: then check that your images really exist and you can access them with the URL, because there is no reason why it does not work..

Comment: Sorry but i’ve already say that the URL is not the problem. Now i found a workaround: if i use infinite scroll there are no problems.